# LibGDX ViewPort keeps squaring up the viewport

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Can anyone shed some light on this behaivor of the viewport or ortographic camera? I expect a rectangular viewport to be drawn but what I get instead is everything squeezed up in a square frame. I uploaded a picture to show you what's going on. The center of the green circle is being drawn on to the point(100,100) so clearly , it looks too disproportioned. The size of the red square is supposed to be 400x400 but judging by the way it looks, it isn't . The aspect ratio is completely off. I don't know what's causing this issue. Ignore the little mario in the center. that's being rendered by another camera soewhere else.

Does any one know what could be causing it?

/**
 * Created by Omer on 11/24/2015.
 */
public class Play extends GameStateBase {

```
public static final int CAMERA_TYPE_SCREEN = 0;
public static final int CAMERA_TYPE_MAP = 1;

private Viewport SCREEN_VIEW;
private Viewport MAP_VIEW;

private OrthographicCamera SCREEN_CAM;
private OrthographicCamera MAP_CAM;

AssaultTrooper assaultTrooper;
GamePad GAME_PAD;

public Play(GameStateManager _gameStateManager) {
    super(_gameStateManager);



    SCREEN_CAM = new OrthographicCamera();
    SCREEN_VIEW = new FitViewport(GameGraphics.VIRTUAL_WIDTH,GameGraphics.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT,SCREEN_CAM);
    SCREEN_VIEW.apply();
    SCREEN_CAM.translate(GameGraphics.VIRTUAL_WIDTH/2,GameGraphics.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2);
    SCREEN_CAM.update();

    MAP_CAM = new OrthographicCamera();
    MAP_VIEW = new FitViewport(GameGraphics.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT,GameGraphics.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT,MAP_CAM);
    MAP_VIEW.apply();
    MAP_CAM.translate(GameGraphics.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2,GameGraphics.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2);
    MAP_CAM.update();

    RENDER_STATE.addCamera(CAMERA_TYPE_SCREEN,SCREEN_CAM);
    RENDER_STATE.addCamera(CAMERA_TYPE_MAP,MAP_CAM);

    GAME_PAD = new GamePad();

    RenderStateManager.changeGameRenderState(RENDER_STATE);
    GAME_PAD.setCameraType(CAMERA_TYPE_SCREEN);
    GAME_PAD.addToRenderState();

    assaultTrooper = new AssaultTrooper(GameSettings.TEAM_BLUE,new Location(200,200));
    assaultTrooper.setCameraType(CAMERA_TYPE_MAP);
    assaultTrooper.addToRenderState();
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch _spriteBatch) {
    try {
        RenderStateManager.RENDERING_STATE.render(_spriteBatch);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void handleInput() {

}

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {

}


@Override
public void dispose() {

}

@Override
public void reSize(int _width, int _height) {
  SCREEN_VIEW.update(_width,_height);
  MAP_VIEW.update(_width,_height);

}
```

}

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<Long,Location> locations;
private ConcurrentHashMap<Long,Sprite> sprites;
private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,OrthographicCamera> cameras;
private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,List<Long>> cameraMapping;
 public void render(SpriteBatch _spriteBatch) throws InterruptedException {

    synchronized (this) {

        for (int key : cameras.keySet()) {
            _spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cameras.get(key).combined);
            _spriteBatch.begin();
            if (cameraMapping.get(key) == null) {
                _spriteBatch.end();
                continue;
            }
            for (long MAPPER : cameraMapping.get(key)) {
                sprites.get(MAPPER).draw(_spriteBatch);

            }
            _spriteBatch.end();
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure to include all code, including your `resize` method. Btw, don't use statics like that, it will hunt you later. If you dont like OOP then dont use java.

Comment: @Xoppa I changed the code. Included the resize method,, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Man, sorry to say, but that is quite some dirty code you have there. Having a wrong projection is probably the least of your concerns. What's up with the `synchronized` and all the `ConcurrentHashMap`s for example? Remove those to start with and please use camelCase instead of ALL_CAPS. Also, your code does not compile, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the parts of the code that relate to this and not everything so it's not going to compile and i need that part of the code to be synchronized. I did however, removed concurrenthashmaps and now using hashmaps. I figured out my problem anyway. Thanks